# Chave estrangeira pode se tornar chave primária?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

exemplificando, tenho duas tabelas: cliente e contato.

A tabela contato contém a coluna telefone do cliente como chave primária, coluna fax e coluna e-mail.
A tabela cliente contém a coluna telefone do cliente como chave primária e chave estrangeira e a coluna nome.

```
+-------------------------------+      +--------------------------------------------+
| contato                       |      | cliente                                    |
+-------------------------------+      +--------------------------------------------+
| telefoneCliente (primary key) |      | telefoneCliente (primary key, foreign key) |
| fax                           |      | nome                                       |
| email                         |      |                                            |
+-------------------------------+      +--------------------------------------------+
```

Primeiro: isso pode acontecer sem criar inconsistência?
Segundo: há alguma maneira do valor de uma chave primária ser o mesmo valor de uma chave primária de outra tabela?

Comment: "há alguma maneira do valor de uma chave primária ser o mesmo valor de uma chave primária de outra tabela?" Se a chave primária de uma é também chave estrangeira na chave primária da outra, então é exatamente isso que vai acontecer; os valores vão necessariamente ser os mesmos (assumindo que para cada linha na tabela `contato` você acrescente depois uma linha na tabela `cliente`).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Primeiramente, respostas às suas perguntas:

P: *Isso pode acontecer sem criar inconsistência?*

R: Na estrutura atual este modelo **permite inconsistência de dados** (um `telefone` sem `Cliente`, por exemplo).

P: *há alguma maneira do valor de uma chave primária ser o mesmo valor de uma chave primária de outra tabela?*

R: **Sim, porém em casos muito específicos**. Se você possui um identificador em duas tabelas com o mesmo valor, para todos os fins práticos você está identificando a mesma entidade; neste caso, porque não ter apenas uma tabela?

Vamos inicialmente analizar o seu modelo de dados. Se eu entendi corretamente, esta seria uma representação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com este modelo, um contato é identificado por um telefone, e este é utilizado para identificar exclusivamente um Cliente.

Problemas com este modelo:

- O que acontece se um Cliente possuir 2 ou mais telefones?
- O que acontece se um Cliente possuir email, mas não telefone?
- O que acontece se 2 clientes compartilharem um mesmo número de telefone?

O seu modelo precisa ser abstrato o suficiente para cobrir o máximo de situações triviais. Um outro aspecto é a definição de chave primária: um valor (ou, alternativamente, valores) que não se repete e que identifica unicamente um registro na sua tabela. Nem telefone nem nome cobrem esta espeficação.

Passo 1: **A criação de um campo `ID` para identificação exclusiva do registro**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Crie um campo especificamente com inicialização única (um autocontador numérico ou `GUID`, por exemplo) que servirá como identificador exclusivo do registro. Crie um campo na sua tabela `contato`, `Cliente_ID`, e utilize-o como chave estrangeira.

Dessa maneira você permite homônimos (que possuirão IDs diferentes) e telefones repetidos, sem violar o seu modelo.

Mas ainda não está bom o suficiente.

Passo 2: **Modelagem dos contatos por tipo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Crie uma tabela, Contato_Tipo, e armazene lá todos os tipos de contato que você precisar. Por exemplo:

```
Contato_Tipo
ID  Descricao
1   Telefone
2   Fax
3   Email
```

Modifique sua tabela `Contato` para, ao invés de armazenar um valor de cada tipo, agora referencie o campo `ID` da tabela `Contato_Tipo` via a chave estrangeira `Contato_Tipo_ID`. Armazene um único valor lá, na coluna `Valor`.

Vamos simular um Cliente, Goku. Seu número de telefone é 555-4433, e seu email é goku@capsulecorp.com. Os valores nas tabelas seriam os seguintes:

```
Cliente
ID    Nome
1     Goku

Contato
ID    Cliente_ID    Contato_Tipo_ID   Valor
1     1             1                 555-4433
2     1             3                 goku@capsulecorp.com
```

Este modelo apresenta grandes vantagens em relação ao anterior. Ele permite 0-N valores de 0-N tipos para cada cliente; e quando a necessidade de acrescentar mais um tipo de contato aparecer (Link para perfil do StackOverflow, por exemplo), você não precisará alterar sua estrutura - apenas adicionar mais um registro à tabela `Contato_Tipo`.

Comment: Sim, mas no caso, eu gostaria de usar o próprio telefone como chave primária, se o cliente tiver mais de um telefone, acho que daria para usar como chave concatenada.

Comment: Nada impede que você use o telefone. Entretanto, considere que você pode estar violando o escopo de entidade - uma entidade Telefone está identificando uma entidade Cliente. Não lhe soa estranho?

Comment: Talvez, mas depende do ponto de vista, escolhi telefone por ele ser um dado relativamente único.

Comment: @OnoSendai: Identificar um cliente pelo telefone não é necessáriamente errado (por exemplo, o Whatsapp faz exatamente isso). Por outro lado, isso só faz sentido se o cliente só puder ter um único telefone - colocar mais de um valor em uma única linha da tabela é pedir pra dar merda (por exemplo, se representarmos up par de telefones como "A|B" não vamos perceber que é o mesmo conjunto de "B|A" ou que é um telefone que também ocorre em "A")

Comment: Como mencionei, @missingno, nada o impede de usar o telefone. Mas situações onde um telefone identifica exclusivamente uma entidade são raríssimas (o WhatsApp sendo a exceção que confirma a regra, e que na verdade usa o telefone como um ID). Mesmo companhias telefônicas identificam usuários primariamente, e associam N telefones a estes.

Comment: @Patrick, a palavra-chave na sua frase é 'relativamente'. E quando não for? O que você vê como sendo a solução ideal?

Comment: Quando não for, vou modificar o programa para que ele se encaixe no banco. Usar esse tipo de identificação é muito mais simples.

Comment: @OnoSendai, não sei se estou errado, mas na primeira imagem, a chave estrangeira não ficaria na tabela contato?

Comment: @Patrick Eu li novamente sua pergunta, e você está correto - eu inverti a conexão no primeiro gráfico. Obrigado! Vou corrigir agora.

Comment: @Patrick: não entendo como o conceito de chave concatenada pode ser útil no problema descrito em sua pergunta.

Comment: @Patrick quanto à modificação do programa, a decisão de modelagem é obviamente sua - porém eu diria que é sempre melhor criar um modelo mais robusto no início que custe pouco esforço de manutenção futura do que um modelo simples que implica em `refactoring` radical.

Comment: @OnoSendai, agora percebi a resposta da primeira pergunta, sobre inconsistência: telefone sem cliente, não seria resolvido apenas colocando a coluna "nome" como not null?

Comment: @user2478690, ignore o que eu disse, viajei.

Answer (score 3):

Não tem problema a chave de uma tabela também ser uma chave estrangeira. Esses conceitos são independentes um do outro.

O conceito de **chave** e **chave primária** serve para restringir os valores entre linhas de uma tabela. Duas linhas de uma tabela não podem ter os mesmos valores nas colunas de uma chave.

Por outro lado, a **chave extrangeira** restringe os valores de uma coluna a apenas valores que existam na tabela referida.

No seu exemplo, a restrição de chave extrangeira significa que só podemos inserir clientes que tiveram seu telefone e fax inseridos na tabela de contatos. Além disso, a restrição de chave primária significa que não podemos ter dois clientes que compartilhem o mesmo telefone.

Comment: Então não há inconsistência? Quanto a criar uma chave concatenada/composta com uma chave estrangeira, é possível?

Comment: Teoricamente, a chave referenciada pela restrição de chave estrangeira pode ser qualquer tipo de chave. No entanto, alguns bancos de dados, como o sqlite e o mysql podem não suportar todos os tipos de chave estrangeira nas configurações padrão. Consulte a documentação do BD que você estiver usando.

Answer (score 3):

Os colegas já explicaram perfeitamente a questão, mas gostaria de somar com um exemplo prático que mostra como essa situação (chave estrangeira E primária) além de possível é muito útil.

Pensemos em uma tabela Produto, que receba produtos de diversas empresas. Ela pode sofrer com o fato de que produtos diferentes podem ter o mesmo id (cada empresa registrou o seus produtos com os seus ids). Updates, por exemplo, iriam bagunçar tudo.
Para solucionar, podemos colocar o coluna idDaEmpresa no Produto, fazer dela uma chave primária E uma foreingkey para a tabela empresa. Produto.idDaEmpresa <--> Empresa.id

```
CREATE TABLE Produto (
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
descricao VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
idDaEmpresa INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Empresa(id),
CONSTRAINT pkProduto PRIMARY KEY (id, idDaEmpresa)
)
```

Comment: "id" seria o código da outra empresa em uma tabela e "idDaEmpresa" seria o código da empresa em questão em outra tabela?

Comment: i seria o código do produto, e idDaEmpresa seria o id da tabela empresa. A ideia é que poderíamos ter vários produtos com o mesmo id, mas nunca dois produtos com o mesmo id E o mesmo idDaEmpresa.

Answer (score 2):

Concordo com os colegas que acima confirmaram que não há incoerência.
É perfeitamente possível e lógico - e digo mais, deve-se pôr! Na dúvida sempre aplique a chave estrangeira.

Vejamos o exemplo de uma entidade usuário que se especializa em pessoa física ou pessoa jurídica.
A chave primária da entidade usuário deve ser a mesma para as especializações. Não posso pôr outra chave e nem trabalhar com composição de chaves, pois permitiria a duplicidade de registros com a mesma chave da tabela usuários. Ex: se a chave da tabela usuarios fosse o cpf e houvesse chave composta nas especializações, como um id inteiro e auto incrementável e o próprio cpf, poderia haver população sem erros (pelo banco) do mesmo cpf em outras tuplas para ambas especializações, o que seria um erro lógico. Pois só existe um cpf para cada usuário.